# How can I apply a git patch from a future version to a past version?

Tags: git, version-control

In the following, `M` is master, `A1` and `A2` are commits on a new branch `A` off  `M`.

`A2` is the changes I'm interested in applying to `B`, without consideration for what happened in `A1`

There aren't any changes in `A2` that depend on `A1` (semantically speaking, I don't care about `A1` as far as `B` is concerned.

```
  A1 - A2
 /
M
 \
  B
```

I can make a patch that, to my eye, looks right. It looks like it only holds `A2`'s changes.

When I apply it with 3 way, it tries to merge in `A1` stuff.

If I apply without 3 way, I can't get it to work, not even a normal-looking merge conflict to fix.

Cherry picking doesn't help either.

```
# The Setup
mkdir git-problem && cd git-problem
git init
echo Original > a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -am "initial"

# Branch A
git checkout -b branch-A
echo A1 >> a.txt
git commit -am "A1 Changes"

echo A2 >> a.txt
git commit -am "A2 Changes, the one's I want in branch-B"

git format-patch HEAD~

# Branch B
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch-B

# Tries to bring in both commits
# git cherry-pick d012465 # the latest commit on branch-A
# git am --3way -- 0001-A2-Changes-the-one-s-I-want-in-branch-B.patch
# git am -- 0001-A2-Changes-the-one-s-I-want-in-branch-B.patch
```

At `M`, `a.txt` is

```
Original
```

At `A2`, `a.txt` is

```
Original
A1
A2
```

At `B`, I would like to make it:

```
Original
A2
```

Comment: Doing exactly your steps, I get merge conflict at the cherry-pick. Do you have any unusual settings. In gitattributes, for example? What `git check-attr -a a.txt` says. What it the output of cherrypick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git is complaining about applying the change set - whether obtained from the file you generated, or the repository itself using `cherry-pick` - because the *context* of the change doesn't match. That is, in order to know where in the file to insert the `A2` line, the merging algorithm needs to be able to find the `A1` line because it knows that `A2` comes right after `A1`. But in the `branch-B` version of the file, there is no `A1` line. So the algorithm gets confused and kicks it back to you for a manual merge.

This is a normal enough situation, and is something you're going to encounter any time you try to apply a set of changes whose context doesn't match between where you're taking it from (in this case revision `A1`) and where you're putting it (in this case revision `B`).

The way I like to resolve this is with `git mergetool`. This invokes an editor-like program which aids you in viewing the places where the context doesn't match and manually choosing how to deal with them. In this example, you're probably going to need to edit that little piece of the file to add the `A2` line yourself.

For completeness, the UNIX `patch` tool has a `--fuzz` option which tells it to ignore parts of the context and search for an imperfect match. Using that option would probably resolve your situation here, if you were using `patch`, but I'm not sure if there's a way to convey it to git.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **interactive rebase** to only apply the changes from `A2` to branch `B` manually. Detail steps as below:

```
git checkout -B B <commit id for A2>
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

In rebase interactive window, change the commit for `A1` as `drop`:

```
pick <commit id for M>
drop <commit id for A1>
pick <commit id for A2>
```

During the rebase, `a.txt` will has conflicts like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Original
=======
Original
A1
A2
>>>>>>> ebd0940... A2
```

You should manually check what’s changed at the version for commit `A1`, and then resolve the conflicts manually. Then it will be what you need.